# JS - for loop with preset variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

My first post. I have searched this forum and the internet, but I haven't found a solution until now.

I'm creating a Panel with some relais with raspberry pi zero. I use socket.io to connect frontend with node.js. This is my code on the server side:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

var emitName = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
var pinNumber = ['4', '17', '27','22','18','23','24']

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  for (var i=0, len=emitName.length; i<len; i++) {
  const RELAY = new Gpio(pinNumber[i], 'out')
  var relayOne = 0; //static variable for current status
  socket.on(emitName[i], function(data) { //get light switch status from client
    relayOne = data;
    if (relayOne != RELAY.readSync()) { //only change LED if status has changed
      RELAY.writeSync(relayOne); //turn LED on or off
    }
  });
}
});
```

The issue i'm facing is when I refresh the browser. The relay status get reset. This is because I'm defining `new Gpio(pinNumber[i], 'out')` inside the for-loop. If I take it out, everything is working as expected. But how can I then make that the for-loop is taking everytime it runs a different relay (raspberry pin)?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks a lot, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gathered from your question I understood it as:

1. You want the initalization of the GPIO pin to happen outside the loop such that it does not get reset each time a new connection is made.
2. You want to still be able to address the correct pin after the initialization has been moved outside the loop.

My suggestion would then be the following:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

const eventToGpio= {
    'one': new Gpio(4, 'out'),
    'two': new Gpio(17, 'out'),
    'three': new Gpio(27, 'out'),
    'four': new Gpio(22, 'out'),
    'five': new Gpio(18, 'out'),
    'six': new Gpio(23, 'out'),
    'seven': new Gpio(24, 'out')
};

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    Object.entries(eventToGpio)
    .forEach(function([event, relay]) {
        socket.on(event, function(data) {
            if(data != relay.readSync()) {
                relay.writeSync(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The initialization of the GPIO pins have been moved outside the loop so they are only initialized once.

Each time a new connection is made, the event handlers are registered without reinitializing the GPIO pins but are still mapped to the correct pins.

I got rid of the `relayOne` variable in the above code sample as I did not see a use for it.

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for. THANKS!

Comment: @skuettel Glad it helped. Would you mind marking the answer as accepted then?